# Interview at 60?

Tags: professionalism, employment

How does one prepare to go into an office (not a real socialized person) and ask someone half my age for a job that pays half of what I'm worth per hour that I'm overqualified for?

Comment: Assuming you have a reason to do this, why do you think it would not be taken at face value by whoever does the interview? I other words, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You are worth exactly what someone is willing to pay you. So if you think you are worth double, probably best to look around and go for a different position at a different company.

Comment: IMO you should try to find the right gig for your expertise and your salary-expectations instead - never mind if you are 60 or 20. Attending interviews that you describe in your question is waisted times on both sides.

Comment: I don't imagine that it would take long for any interviewer to discern that you have an incredibly bad attitude and would make a terrible hire.  Fix YOUR problem first, then start looking for a job.

Comment: @GodsSickJoke - I think the question is very valid (and something we'll all encounter at some stage if we haven't already). I'll vote to reopen but please rephrase the question to be more suited to help others as well.

Answer (score 11):

Asking someone half your age: If you can't respect people for who they are, independent of age, you have no business interviewing with them. I certainly wouldn't hire someone with that attitude.

Half of what you are worth: You are worth what someone is willing to pay you. Again, fix that attitude or you don't belong in the interview.

Overqualified: Again, dump the arrogance. They are hiring for a particular set of skills. If you exceed those requirements, great, but not necessarily relevant right now.

What you need is a good answer to why you want this particular job, why you won't vanish the moment you hear rumor of a better offer or get bored, and whether you can be a pleasant person to work with. It sounds like you haven't answered those questions to your own satisfaction, never mind theirs. That isn't their problem, it's yours. Fix it. Or don't waste everyone's time by applying.

(Yes, I know, you're just blowing off steam. Go ahead and get it out of your system, then leave it there and decide whether you would rather be a Walmart greeter. Not knocking the greeters; I know some quite competent people who have supplemented Social Security doing exactly that.)

---

Follow-up: My own plan, if I go back into the formal workforce, is to seek out a nonprofit or other charitable organization that needs my skills and *explicitly* explain I will work for less than my past salary because I consider the differential a contribution to a cause I support. It would be great  if I could treat the difference as an in-kind donation for tax purposes, but that may be hard to justify.